# ESLINT infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

So i used eslint pretty normally until I added a specific rule, then eslint seemed to just loop infinite :

```
> api@1.0.0 pretest /api
> eslint .
```

this just stay forever. Never ending the process. So i removed that specific rule again, but it didnt fixed the problem.

This is my eslint file at the moment, but even if i change the rules it would still go infinite.

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb-base/legacy",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "rules": {
        "global-require" : 0,
        "no-unused-vars" : 0
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    }
}
```

this is my rule in the package.json :

```
"pretest": "eslint .",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ignoring `node_modules/` folder:

```
eslint . --ext .js --ignore-pattern node_modules/
```

---

Also, you can ignore specific folders using `.eslintignore` file in the root of your project:

### .eslintignore

```
/dist
/node_modules
```

Comment: I tried both adding it in my eslintignore file and then directly in the cmd line like you showed it but it is still infinite looping

Comment: It just stopped looping giving me a shit ton of errors but i cannot go to the first file name. I tried adding you suggestion

Comment: Oh .... I found the problem. It was linting in my public folder with my images.... For some reason some js files were created there ?

Comment: Great that it helped! Try adding that public folder as well to the `.eslintignore` file :)

Comment: What public folder?